# Необработанное исключение. Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку

Tags: c#, .net

[image: Ошибка при запуске]
При запуске приложения на другом компьютере возникате ошибка: **"Необработанное исключение. Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку"**, хотя на компьютере, на котором ведется разработка ничего подобного нет. Все dll находятся в папке с программой. Подскажите пожалуйста - что не так?

Comment: Добавте ваш код и сообшение об ошибке как текст прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Скорее всего, при разработке какая-то сборка лежала в GAC. А теперь её в GAC нет.

Comment: Вроде как в GAC ничего, что используется приложением нет, ни на компьютере на котором разрабатывалось ни на котором ошибка.

Comment: может путь до этой DLL был жёстко задан в проге, а не как относительный? (если указано только имя файла, то по-умолчанию он ищется в папке рядом с исполняемым файлом приложения)

Comment: Попробуйте переподключить эти библиотеки

Comment: Пути до этой длл не указывались, все эти дллки подтянулись из nuget пакетов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что если у C++/CLI-сборки не находится одна из нативных зависимостей, загрузить её невозможно.

В случае управляемых зависимостей, загрузка откладывается до момента первого использования, и вы получаете сообщение о том модуле, который невозможно загрузить. Но нативные зависимости грузятся сразу. Раз вы их с собой не таскаете, то они должны быть проинсталлированы на целевой системе, а их отсутствие приводит к невозможности загрузить модуль.

---

Для определения недостающих зависимостей имеет смысл использовать [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) (обычно известный как depends.exe).

Comment: VladD, можете подсказать, каким инструментом можно подсмотреть, а каких нативных зависимостей не хватает?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов: Я обычно пользуюсь этим: http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Спасибо, я понимаю, что это наглость, но я бы добавил Вашу рекомендацию, по части инструмента а ответ :)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов: Хорошая идея, спасибо! Так и сделаю.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел чем отличаются конфиги компьютеров и установил на компьютер, на котором выдавало ошибку - Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64). И все заработало, ошибка исчезла.

Что за магия?

Comment: Redistributable это в т.ч. набор DLL, видимо ваша ClrWrapper.dll что-то использовала оттуда.